# What are the operating hours of the Heathrow free train shuttle between terminals 4 and 2?

Tags: transit, lhr

Does anyone know if the free shuttle train runs 24 hours, if not what time does it start?

Answer (score 7):

The free train between terminal 4 and 2/3 is part of **TfL Rail**'s Heathrow-Paddington line. Some services go only to terminal 2/3; others continue to Paddington (and are not free except for the bit between terminals 4 and 2/3).

They run from roughly 5 AM to midnight on most days; 6 AM to midnight on Sundays.

---

If you're *transiting*, you probably won't want the train (which is landside of immigration), but the interterminal airside transfer buses, though.

Comment: I believe the underground is also free between the three Heathrow stations, so the OP could use that from terminal 4 to terminal 2. That has similar operating hours, except that there's some night service, the nights after friday and saturday.

Comment: @Henrik: Ah, I wasn't aware of that. It looks like one needs an Oyster or contactless card to get through the ticket gates there, even if they won't get charged.